# Retrieve iOS videocamera resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, resolution

I need to retrieve the resolution in pixels of a movie captured by iOS camera of the iPhone...
Is there a library like UIDevice that check which type of device I'm using, also for the camera information?

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends in which mode you'll start capturing video.

According to this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW30

You can try to capture video with `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` preset, and than check what's the size of captured image.

This should give you highest video resolution in recording mode.

Comment: I don't want to capture a video, I want only understand first of all what is the camera resolution for video...